# Running aggregate function within dmapply (ddR package)

Tags: r, dataframe, parallel-processing, aggregate, distributed-computing

I would like to run the `aggregate` function *within* the [**`dmapply`**](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ddR/vignettes/README.html) function as offered through the [`ddR`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ddR/index.html) package.

### Desired results

The desired results reflect a simple output generated via `aggregate` in base:

```
aggregate(
  x = mtcars$mpg,
  FUN = function(x) {
    mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)
  },
  by = list(trans = mtcars$am)
)
```

which produces:

```
  trans        x
1     0 17.14737
2     1 24.39231
```

## Attempt - [`ddmapply`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ddR/vignettes/README.html)

I would like to arrive at the same results while utilising `ddmapply`, as attempted below:

```
# ddR
require(ddR)

# ddR object creation
distMtcars <- as.dframe(mtcars)

# Aggregate / ddmapply
dmapply(
  FUN = function(x, y) {
    aggregate(FUN = mean(x, na.rm = TRUE),
              x = x,
              by = list(trans = y))
  },
  distMtcars$mpg,
  y = distMtcars$am,
  output.type = "dframe",
  combine = "rbind"
)
```

The code fails:

> *Error in `match.fun(FUN)` :    `'mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)'` is not a
>   function, character or symbol Called from: `match.fun(FUN)`*

---

## *Updates*

Fixing error pointed out by [@Mike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6105720/mike-h) removes the error, however, does not produce the desired result. The code:

```
# Avoid namespace conflict with other packages
ddR::collect(
  dmapply(
    FUN = function(x, y) {
      aggregate(
        FUN = function(x) {
          mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)
        },
        x = x,
        by = list(trans = y)
      )
    },
    distMtcars$mpg,
    y = distMtcars$am,
    output.type = "dframe",
    combine = "rbind"
  )
)
```

yields:

```
[1] trans x    
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Comment: I think it's because you left out the `function(x) mean(x...)` in your `dmapply` call. `Aggregate` will give you the same error if you do: `FUN = mean(x, na.rm = T)`

Comment: @MikeH. Well spotted, I've fixed that. The code runs but the produced results are not equivalent of what would be obtained by running an ordinary aggregate in base.

Comment: It's not going to give you the same results as the base `aggregate` since you are `mapply`ing it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works fine for me if you change your aggregate function to be consistent with the one you call earlier: `FUN = function(x) mean(x, na.rm = T)`. The reason it can't find `mean(x, na.rm = T)` is because it isn't a function (it's a function call), rather `mean` is a function.

Also it will give you `NA` results unless you change your `x = distMtcars$mpg` to `x = collect(distMtcars)$mpg`. Same for y. With all that said, I think this should work for you:

```
res <-dmapply(
  FUN = function(x, y) {
    aggregate(FUN = function(x) mean(x, na.rm = TRUE),
              x = x,
              by = list(trans = y))
  },
  x = list(collect(distMtcars)$mpg),
  y = list(collect(distMtcars)$am),
  output.type = "dframe",
  combine = "rbind"
)
```

Then you can do `collect(res)` to see the result.

```
collect(res)
#  trans        x
#1     0 17.14737
#2     1 24.39231
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the useful contribution. It's close to a solution; however `dim(ddR::collect(res))` produces `[1] 1 64` where it should `[1] 2 2`.

Comment: @Konrad I don't think you want `dmapply` then. Because `mapply` matches the 1st x to the first y and performs a function

Comment: Np - if you want to use `dmapply` you can set `x` and `y` to be lists so it will "trick" it into doing the aggregate the way you want. See my edited answer